# Wordpress sections of pages hidden

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, wsod

Ive been creating a landing page with osmosis child theme. I've managed to break the site.

When I'm in editor/logged in the page loads fine however, in live preview the pages aren't loading below the menu. The new landing page I've began setting up loads fine.

I've tried deactivating plug ins and activating again but this doesn't seem to make any difference.

I also tried htaccess but got locked out.

It seems the elements are there but just hidden.

Please help, 
thanks

http://www.tokyo-travelassist.com
http://www.tokyo-travelassist.com/landing/

Comment: `#grve-main-content { position: relative; z-index: 10; opacity: 0; }` - that opacity value is the reason nothing shows ... but don’t ask me where that rule comes from, or what sense it is supposed to make in the first place.

Comment: thank you, it only gets testimonials up for some reason, cant manage to overwrite it in css